# xml explicit type attribute

Tags: sql, xml, attributes, tags

I try to conclude my SQL for a feed output... but one more complication rise to me. First of all I want to appreciate that I'm not an expert of SQL for XML output... but hope in the help of someone.

Using this query

```
SELECT 
    1487997 as ExternalId,
    'This is a name' as [Name]
INTO #sample

DROP TABLE #colors
SELECT 
    1487997 as ExternalId,
    'BV_FE_FAMILY:Green' as [Color]
INTO #colors
UNION 
SELECT
    1487997 as ExternalId,
    'Green' as [Color]

SELECT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    NULL AS [EliminaTAG!1], -- empty root element
    NULL AS [Product!2!ExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!Name!cdata],
    NULL AS [Product!2!]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    ExternalId,  
    [Name],
    (
     SELECT  
       c.[Color] as Value
     FROM #colors  c 
     WHERE (ff.ExternalId = c.ExternalId)   
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'), ROOT('Attributes'), TYPE)
FROM #sample ff 
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

I'm close to my scope... but I need a id="BV_FE_FAMILY" and id="BV_FE_EXPAND" into TAG...

```
<Attributes>
<Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
    <Value>Green</Value>
<Attribute>
<Attribute id="BV_FE_EXPAND">
    <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:Green</Value>
<Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

My result is... miss "ID=....."

```
    <EliminaTAG>
      <Product>
        <ExternalId>1487997</ExternalId>
        <Name><![CDATA[This is a name]]></Name>
        <Attributes xmlns="">
          <Attribute>
              <Value>Green</Value>
          </Attribute>
          <Attribute>
              <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:Green</Value>
          </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
      </Product>
   </EliminaTAG>
```

Thanks to everyone who will give me right advise.
ALEN, Italy

Comment: `FOR XML EXPLICIT` is a real head ache... The only reason you might need it for, is the `CDATA` section. If this is not an externally enforced requirement, you should solve this with `FOR XML PATH`. Semantically there's no difference between a `CDATA` section and a properly escaped *normal* `text()` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, `FOR XML EXPLICIT` is a rather clumsy choice. But there are some requirements, which cannot be solved otherwise...

So, if you really need this, you might solve it a bit easier:

```
SELECT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    ff.ExternalId AS [Product!1!ExternalId!element],
    ff.Name AS [Product!1!Name!cdata],
    (
     SELECT  'SomeValueForId' AS [@id]
            ,c.Color AS [Value]
     FROM #colors c
     WHERE c.ExternalId=ff.ExternalId
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'),ROOT('Attributes'),TYPE
    ) AS [Product!1!]
FROM #sample ff 
FOR XML EXPLICIT,ROOT('EliminaTAG');
```

The result

```
<EliminaTAG>
  <Product>
    <ExternalId>1487997</ExternalId>
    <Name><![CDATA[This is a name]]></Name>
    <Attributes xmlns="">
      <Attribute id="SomeValueForId">
        <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:Green</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute id="SomeValueForId">
        <Value>Green</Value>
      </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
  </Product>
</EliminaTAG>
```

I do not get the logic, where the **content** of your `id` attributes comes from, this is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help and advise...
I resolved with his code, from yours:

```
SELECT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    ff.ExternalId AS [Product!1!ExternalId!element],
    ff.Name AS [Product!1!Name!cdata],
    (
     SELECT  
            CASE
                WHEN CHARINDEX('BV_FE_FAMILY', c.Color) > 0 THEN 'BV_FE_EXPAND' 
                ELSE 'BV_FE_FAMILY'
            END AS [@id]
            ,c.Color AS [Value]
     FROM #colors c
     WHERE c.ExternalId=ff.ExternalId
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'),ROOT('Attributes'),TYPE
    ) AS [Product!1!]
FROM #sample ff 
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

this is the result of my output

```
<Product>
  <ExternalId>1487997</ExternalId>
  <Name><![CDATA[This is a name]]></Name>
  <Attributes xmlns="">
    <Attribute id="BV_FE_EXPAND">
      <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:Green</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
      <Value>Green</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
</Product>
```

It's possible remove this xmlns="" ?.
Currently, I'll remove it during ETL process for the creation of XML file directly into SSIS... but if there is a clean way directly from T-SQL, I would prefer...
Thanks anyway Shnugo!
ALEN

P.S.: this is another version using (as you said) FROM XML PATH, but how can I insert cdata for some elements? this choice has remove xmlns=""...

```
SELECT
    ff.ExternalId ,
    ff.Name,
    (
     SELECT  
            CASE
                WHEN CHARINDEX('BV_FE_FAMILY', c.Color) > 0 THEN 'BV_FE_EXPAND' 
                ELSE 'BV_FE_FAMILY'
            END AS [@id]
            ,c.Color AS [Value]
     FROM #colors c
     WHERE c.ExternalId=ff.ExternalId
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'),ROOT('Attributes'),TYPE
    ) 
FROM #sample ff 
FOR XML PATH('Product'), ROOT('Products');
```

THIS is my final solution (CAST + REPLACE + CAST):

```
SELECT
    ff.ExternalId ,
    ff.Name,
    CAST(REPLACE(CAST((
     SELECT  
            CASE
                WHEN CHARINDEX('BV_FE_FAMILY', c.Color) > 0 THEN 'BV_FE_EXPAND' 
                ELSE 'BV_FE_FAMILY'
            END AS [@id]
            ,c.Color AS [Value]
     FROM #colors c
     WHERE c.ExternalId=ff.ExternalId
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'),ROOT('Attributes'),TYPE
    )  as varchar(MAX)),' xmlns=""','') as xml)
FROM #sample ff 
FOR XML PATH('Product'), ROOT('Products');
```

my clean result output:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <ExternalId>1487997</ExternalId>
    <Name>This is a name</Name>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute id="BV_FE_EXPAND">
        <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:Green</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
        <Value>Green</Value>
      </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

ALEN

Comment: The `xmlns=""` is a well known and annoying issue. Using `FOR XML` in sub-selects will create namespace declarations in places where you do not want them. This is not wrong yet bloating your XML and sometimes problematic with (to strict) schema validation. A cast to string and `REPLACE` is a good workaround.

Comment: About `CDATA`. When you use the cast to `VARCHAR` (btw: better use `NVARCHAR`) and you write it back into native XML the `CDATA` will disappear. SQL-Server developer decided not even to support this anymore. `CDATA` is not needed actually... Your *clean result output* has no `CDATA`. If you can live without, there's no need for the casting and replacing at all. Try your own code without the `cast` and `replace` and it will be okay without the `xmlns=""` - but without the `CDATA` too...

Comment: Yes your right... I replace nvarchar(max) that's better and remove to REPLACE... with double CAST all seems to be absolutely perfect.
Thanks for you time.
Thank you very much.
ALEN

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code:

```
SELECT
    ff.ExternalId ,
    ff.Name as Name,
    'http://www.mysite.it/imgege.jpg' as URL,
    CAST(CAST((
     SELECT  
            CASE
                WHEN CHARINDEX('BV_FE_FAMILY', c.Color) > 0 THEN 'BV_FE_EXPAND' 
                ELSE 'BV_FE_FAMILY'
            END AS [@id]
            ,c.Color AS [Value]
     FROM #colors c
     WHERE c.ExternalId=ff.ExternalId
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'),ROOT('Attributes'),TYPE
    )  as nvarchar(MAX)) as xml)
FROM #sample ff 
FOR XML PATH('Product'), ROOT('Products');
```

and my output...

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <ExternalId>1487997</ExternalId>
    <Name>This is a name</Name>
    <URL>http://www.mysite.it/imgege.jpg</URL>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute id="BV_FE_EXPAND">
        <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:Green</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
        <Value>Green</Value>
      </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
  </Product>
</Products>
```